# Disable focus in WPF DataGrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a C# WPF **DataGrid**. In administrator mode, user can highline and select rows in DataGrid and key down a "D" to remove them using `PreviewKeyDown`. In operator mode, this feature will be disabled and user can only scroll and read rolls but cannot highline or select rows to delete.

[image]

I can get the rows to be highlined and removed. But I don't know how to disable this feature.
I tried:

- `IsReadOnly = false` renders the DataGrid not scrollable
- `Focusable = false` user can still highline and select the rows
- `IsHitTestVisible = false` still visible..

How?

Answer (score 4):

You could disable selection in the `DataGrid` while still keeping sorting, scrolling etc. by setting `IsEnabled="False"` on `DataGridRow`.

*This has the sideeffect that most elements get the "grayed-out"/disabled look, however this is not the case for `TextBlocks`.*

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```